# How to select two random rows with same category in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner in javascript and nodejs, and not having much knowledge of mysql.
These are the column names of my MySQL table whose name is `cars`:

- Name
- model
- TransmissionType
- EngineSize
- VehicleSize
- BodyType

I want to randomly select `Name` and `model` from `cars`, but the category must match which will be decided by the other four coloumns: `TransmissionType`, `EngineSize`, `VehicleSize` and `Body Type`, in such a way that randomly selected cars must share same values for `engine`, `TransmissionType`, `VehicheSize` and `BodyType`. Output should be in two rows only.

Engine size has values: `3.2, 3.5, 1.6, 5.2, 2.0, 2.2`

TransmissionType has values: `Manual` and `Automatic`

VehicleSize has values: `Compact`, `MidSize` and `Large`.

BodyType has values: `Car`, `van` and `truck`.

What query should I write to achieve this? Please help.

I did this, and the query is working fine, but there are too many sub-queries are running in it, is it possible to achieve this using not more den 2-3 sub-queries?

```
SELECT Name, model 
FROM cars 
WHERE EngineSize IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT EngineSize FROM cars  ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1 ) AS A)  
AND TransmissionType IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT TransmissionType  FROM cars ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1 ) AS B)
AND BodyType IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT BodyType  FROM cars ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1 ) AS C)   
AND VehicleSize IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT VehicleSize` FROM cars ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 1 ) AS D)    
LIMIT 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are in search of a list of vehicles matching certain categories, you can do this;

```
SELECT Name, model, Id * RAND() AS random_no
FROM   cars
WHERE  EngineSize = '2.2'
AND    TransmissionType = 'Automatic'
AND    VehicleSize = 'Large'
AND    BodyType = 'Car'
ORDER by random_no
LIMIT 1
```

And if you're doing it dynamically, you should pass the values (*hardcoded in the above example*) by parameters from your javascript.

Comment: Actually my code needs random rows, this query will show a specific result.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: Do you have an Id in your table?

Comment: Yes, ID filed is there in the table.

Comment: Database is very huge, I cannot pass parameters using javascript. It will have to be in SQL query alone as per requirement.

Comment: So, you'll have to hardcode your query as the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, model
FROM   cars
WHERE  EngineSize = '2.2'
AND    TransmissionType = 'Automatic'
AND    VehicleSize = 'Large'
AND    BodyType = 'Car'
ORDER by RAND()
LIMIT 2
```

This select will select all results fitting the where clause, reorder the results in a random way, then limit the return to the first 2 fitting the criteria.  See [this blog](http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random), these [instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast) for more details.